# Docker Fails When It's Run From System

Tags: docker, container

## Problem

I can run docker manually

`sudo dockerd` or `/etc/init.d/docker start`

but not as a service.

#### System

```
Linux g4070 5.4.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 27 22:54:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Lin

Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:18:20 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:16:15 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0


Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 9
 Server Version: 20.10.5
 Storage Driver: devicemapper
  Pool Name: docker-253:0-54002895-pool
  Pool Blocksize: 65.54kB
  Base Device Size: 10.74GB
  Backing Filesystem: ext4
  Udev Sync Supported: true
  Data file: /dev/loop3
  Metadata file: /dev/loop21
  Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
  Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
  Data Space Used: 368MB
  Data Space Total: 107.4GB
  Data Space Available: 107GB
  Metadata Space Used: 17.9MB
  Metadata Space Total: 2.147GB
  Metadata Space Available: 2.13GB
  Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74GB
  Deferred Removal Enabled: true
  Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
  Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
  Library Version: 1.02.167 (2019-11-30)
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc version: ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-66-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.674GiB
 Name: g4070
 ID: 7LHW:SAWD:UW57:6FWM:MISB:LKH4:6NIA:ZNWQ:GJPA:XXLK:A3EI:7UVH
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpu shares support
WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release.
WARNING: devicemapper: usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
         Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
```

---

## Running Docker

I have tried to run docker few ways but only it was possible to do it manually.

#### Output of `sudo service docker start`

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

#### Output of `sudo systemctl start docker`

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

#### Automatic start fails when ever a new system is installed

```
sudo apt install cgroupfs-mount
...
Unpacking cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─docker.conf
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-03-03 12:23:21 +0545; 6ms ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 86196 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/mnt/docker-data --storage-driver=overlay --storage-opt=dm.basesize=30G (code=exited, status=1/F
AILURE)
   Main PID: 86196 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of docker-ce-rootless-extras:
 docker-ce-rootless-extras depends on docker-ce; however:
  Package docker-ce is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package docker-ce-rootless-extras (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cgroupfs-mount (1.4) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) .
..
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
 docker-ce-rootless-extras
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

#### Output of `journactl -xe`

```
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 03 12:27:09 g4070 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 5797 and the job result is failed.
```

#### Manual, output of `sudo dockerd`

```
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.199161171+05:45] Starting up                                  
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.204120548+05:45] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.205022694+05:45] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.205048857+05:45] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.205083723+05:45] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.205099311+05:45] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.206048454+05:45] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.206069262+05:45] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.206088901+05:45] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.206101916+05:45] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:51.289599183+05:45] ignoring event                                container=784e314cf411d8f314777582559876069f3bbf8d86ce88923daa4d3db6a3a5f9 module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.432289971+05:45] Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Please use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `man dockerd` to refer to dm.thinpooldev section.  storage-driver=devicemapper
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.485540322+05:45] Base device already exists and has filesystem ext4 on it. User specified filesystem  will be ignored.  storage-driver=devicemapper
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:52.542597632+05:45] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: devicemapper 
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.542678785+05:45] [graphdriver] WARNING: the devicemapper storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release 
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.668450021+05:45] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit 
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.668523341+05:45] Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler 
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.668557411+05:45] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight 
WARN[2021-03-03T12:45:52.668583887+05:45] Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device 
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:52.669019536+05:45] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:54.319361138+05:45] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:54.977967148+05:45] Loading containers: done.                    
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:55.018784152+05:45] Docker daemon                                 commit=363e9a8 graphdriver(s)=devicemapper version=20.10.5
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:55.018938010+05:45] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2021-03-03T12:45:55.066237573+05:45] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

---

## Attempts To Resolve

#### Uninstall and reinstall

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall. Even rebooted the system after uninstall. I can start manually but not as a service.

#### Failed trial with start/stop cgroup

As there was listed some warning with `cgroups`, I even tried this approach which did not work out.

```
service docker stop
service containerd stop
cgroupfs-umount
cgroupfs-mount
service containerd start
service docker start
```

Well, I was unable to `sudo cgroupfs-umount`

```
rmdir: failed to remove 'blkio': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'cpu': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'cpu,cpuacct': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'cpuacct': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'cpuset': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'devices': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'freezer': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'hugetlb': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'memory': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'net_cls': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'net_cls,net_prio': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'net_prio': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'perf_event': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'pids': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'rdma': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove 'systemd': Read-only file system
```

---

## Stop/Disable Docker Service

There is a warning message thrown while stopping docker.

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker stop` or `sudo service docker stop` or `sudo systemctl stop docker`

```
Stopping docker (via systemctl): docker.serviceWarning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by: docker.socket
```

`sudo /etc/init.d/docker status`

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-03-31 16:43:40 +0545; 6s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 107187 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 107187 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The warning means if we try to connect to the docker socket while the docker service is not running, then systemd will automatically start docker. It can be suppressed by deleting docker.socket and docker.service files but that might not help re-run docker, so must be done

Message thrown when I try to disable docker via `sudo systemctl disable docker`

```
Synchronizing state of docker.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable docker
```

Removed the warning message by unmasking the docker service.

Masking a service prevents the service from being started manually or automatically, which is a stronger version of disable. Masking disable all symlinks of the specified unit file are removed.

```
systemctl unmask docker.service
systemctl unmask docker.socket
systemctl list-unit-files | grep docker // Check the status
```

Comment: I think you need to remove and reinstall `docker-ce` and make sure that all packages are installed and configured.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I did try that but missed to mention the point, which I have updated now. It failed as well. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Well, obviously if the reinstall failed, it's no wonder that docker fails as well. I believe the issue is package and dependency problems, so that's what should be solved for this to work.

Comment: The problem is with, as titled, it is possible to run manually, it works fine. It's just the other parts as mentioned. @ArturMeinild, thanks again.